# How to have my cleanup method called whenever my application needs more memory

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a cleanup routine that converts references to stale objects (which are good to have around given sufficient memory) into weak references. I want this routine to be called whenever my application is running out of memory. I have a background thread which calls this method at periodic intervals. But I am concerned about what could happen when there is a memory crunch situation between successive runs of this routine.

What should I do to have this method called whenever the application would need more memory?

Comment: Are you writing new GC ?

Comment: I am implementing an LRU cache..the cleanup routine marks entries for eviction from cache

Comment: Can you use only weak reference in cache? So that GC may act on dead objects? Am I missing something?

Comment: If I do that, theres no way to enforce LRU eviction policy..every object referenced in the cache becomes an equal candidate for eviction..the situation demands only the least recently used object to be evicted

Comment: Is there actually a problem you're trying to solve here? What are your peak memory usage requirements? Have you done any profiling that indicates there *is* a problem to be solved, and exactly the memory usages you're going to face?

Answer (score 1):

You might think of using a PerformanceCounter to keep track of process memory usage, and when your process memory usage goes past a certain limit you can call your routine.

Check these links:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7d8a6640-919d-47d8-8e73-586fb7ac261e/get-processs-memory?forum=csharpgeneral

http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx